# How do I execute the method of a class every 2 minutes?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to execute a method of a class every two minutes with the node-cron library

```
cron.schedule('*/1 * * * *', () => {
    let aa = new PsiController;
    aa.getApiGoogleDesktop(req, res)

});

//.....
class PsiController {

    public async getApiGoogleDesktop(req: Request, res: Response) {
        console.log('ABC', urlParams.category[1]);
```

but I get an error:
Cannot find name 'req'
Cannot find name 'res'

Comment: In your call to `getApiGoogleDesktop`, you are referencing `req` and `res`, but it doesn't appear to be defined based on what you are showing.

Comment: `cron.schedule('*/1 * * * *', (req:Request, res:Response) ` but I get this error: `Error Catch TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\Rafael\PerformanceATG\performanceATG\server\build\controllers\psiControllers.js:96:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Can you please include all relevant code for this problem?

Comment: You can't just make things up in programming. There is a reason `getApiGoogleDesktop` takes `req` and `res`; it depends on those variables. If you can't get references to them, then you can't use that function from `cron`.